# Possible to update cache from subdomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

is it possible to renew or reach the cached data from subdomain?

For instance I have a blog domain (http://foo.com) and my blog admin is in the subdomain (http://admin.foo.com) and they are in same hosting. In blog page I'm caching articles. When I added new article from adminpage I want to renew the cache so people on the blog page they can see new article.
I also wrote same cached method when I added new article to renew cache to admin side but nothing happened.

I'm using HttpCache.

```
CacheHelper.Add("Articles", myArticles, 180, CacheEnum.HttpCache);

HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
                    name,
                    obj,
                    null,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minutes),
                    Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                    System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal,
                    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update main domain cache from sub domain. Because both main and sub domain are using different cache and session area on IIS.

But you can use http post.
If you send request a key to main URL, you can getting value key on main domain URL and you can process by key.